# Change keyboard layout on Linux without X11

Tags: console, keyboard, yocto, keyboard-layout

I built a Yocto/Poky (zeus) minimal core image (without X11) for an embedded device and I would like to change the keyboard layout for the console. I tried the following:

```
$ localectl set-keymap fr
$ localectl status
  System Locale: LANG=C
      VC Keymap: fr
     X11 Layout: fr
      X11 Model: pc105
    X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

This did not do anything (neither on an ssh-console nor on the serial terminal). Also this did not have any effect:

```
$ loadkeys /usr/share/keymaps/i386/azerty/fr.map.gz
```

What else could I try? Or any clue what could prevent the changing of the keyboard layout?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158816/loadkeys-has-almost-no-effect. For the ssh console you will get a error "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console" if you use something different than root user. loadkeys over ssh connection does not work, the keyboard layout is controlled by your ssh client.  You could try loadkeys -C /dev/console cz to change serial keyboard